# Converting .txt file to .csv using pandas and then change the csv file to 2D numpy array for plotting?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, csv

I am trying to convert data that has 2 columns and about 3000 rows to a CSV or excel file. I want to add multiple txt files to the same excel later and plot all of them in the same graph for comparison. But I cannot understand how to change the string type to float. But in the CSV file that pandas save, it is saved as numbers and its possible to make a graph within the CSV without problems.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv

os.chdir(r/....)

M1 = pd.read_csv('M1 - 2020_16 jan maybe fbeta.txt', header=0, delimiter=' ', dtype=float)
M1.to_csv('M1.csv')

#print(M1)

M2 = csv.reader(open("M1.csv"))
x = list(M2)
M2 = np.array(x).astype("float")

print(M2)

#plt.plot(M1)
#plt.plot(M2[5,1])
#plt.show()
```

The error I always get is

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is `print (M1.dtypes)` ?

Comment: I checked it like this

    import pandas as pd
    import os
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import csv

    os.chdir(r.....)

    M1 = pd.read_csv('M1 - 2020_16 jan maybe fbeta.txt', header=0, delimiter=' ', 
    dtype=float)
    M1.to_csv('M1.csv')

    print(M1.dtypes)

it returns the following 

##YUNITS=%T    float64   -------   this is the header
dtype: object